# Laravel extend blade and pass array as parameter

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have searched a lot regarding this topic and didn't find much on the web so I started to research and create a complete article on this topic but I am unable to understand some things here, making basic custom tags in blade is easy like

```
@search @endsearch or @title('something')
```

but what if I want to do something like below

```
@cache('sidebar',10,[$silver,$gold,$platinum])
  html tags come here
@endcache
```

At present I am doing it like this

```
@cache('sidebar_',10,function() use ($silver_sidebar,$gold_sidebar))

@endcache

$pattern = Blade::createOpenMatcher('cache');
$replace = "<?php echo PageCache::cache$2 { ?>";
$view = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $view);

// Replace closing tag
$view = str_replace('@endcache', '<?php }); ?>', $view);
```

How to parse it to separate three parameters and get content between end and start tag? Your help is appreciated. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is more than 1 year old now, but I'm sharing a solution if somebody else need it in the future.

Using the first example:

```
@cache('sidebar', 10, [ $silver, $gold, $platinum ])
    html tags come here
@endcache
```

It's possible to do something like this:

```
Blade::extend(function ($view) {
  $pattern = Blade::createOpenMatcher('cache');
  $pattern = rtrim($pattern, '/') . '(.*?)@endcache/s';

  $matches = [];
  preg_match($pattern, $view, $matches);
  $content = '';

  if (count($matches) > 3) {
    $content = addslashes($matches[3]);
  }

  $replace = "<?php echo PageCache::cache$2, '{$content}'); ?>";
  $view = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $view);

  return $view;
});
```

Explaining the code:

1. We extend the pattern to match the content between `@cache` and `@endcache`. Note the use of **`s` modifier** in the expression. This way we can match multiple lines with a `.` (dot).
2. Check if the expression matched something using `count($matches)` and assign it to `$content`.
3. Finally we replace the blade tag by the function call. Since our pattern already matches the open and close tags and all content between them, we don't need to worry about replace the closing tag or something else.

This way you can get the content between tags (`@cache` and `@endcache`) in your function:

```
class PageCache {
  public static function cache($name, $num, $args, $content) {
    return stripslashes($content);
  }
}
```

Based on the example above you'll have:

```
$name = 'sidebar';
$num = 10;
$args = [ $silver, $gold, $platinum ];
```

I'm also simply returning the content in my example, but you can do something more interesting there.